# Detect open sides of a box

Tags: ros, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Guys,
I am using a Baxter and ROS Groovy. I am given a box with one side missing. I want to use both the  arm cameras to detect which side is missing and then be able to use the appropriate arm to go in and out of the box.
How can i achieve this task ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182835/detect-open-sides-of-a-box/) by [ktiwari9](https://answers.ros.org/users/18753/ktiwari9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend that you be specific in asking questions to get the support you need. Are you familair with [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)? Start by developing the vision part of the project and detect the missing side. If you have questions, go to [OpenCV Answers](http://answers.opencv.org/questions/) and ask your OpenCV related questions.

---

Originally posted by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) with karma: 194 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ktiwari9](https://answers.ros.org/users/18753/ktiwari9/) on 2014-07-03**:
I am basically given a cardboard box with one face missing. I need to figure out a vision based scheme that detects which of the 5 visible faces is missing. I have skimmed through opencv and did not find anything useful.